# how to validate character and number in one textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

The max size of textbox is given as 11. I want to print first 4 characters as alphabets and next 7 characters as numbers. Please give me a solution in javascript only.

```
function Myfunction2() {
    var x2 = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var re = /^[A-za-z]+$/;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        y = x2charAt(i);
        if (re.test(x2.value)) {
            alert("please enter char only");
        }
    }
}

function Myfunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
    for (i = 5; i < 11; i++) {
        y = x.charAt(i);
        if (y == " " || isNaN(y)) {
            alert("not numeric");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need one regex  `/^[a-z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/i`

Comment: So you want to ensure you have a string that has exactly 4 letters followed by exactly 7 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it against an expected pattern:

```
/^[a-z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/i.test(value);
```

You could bind this to the actual input element as well to test it with each keystroke:

```
​var supercode = document.getElementById("supercode"),
    rePattern = /^[a-z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/i;

supercode.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    this.style.borderColor = rePattern.test(this.value) ? "green" : "red" ;
}, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RfMK7/

Comment: @Derek That would work also, though I personally find it to be slightly less intelligible for your average reader.